# The plural form for letter grades

Tags: punctuation, apostrophe

I'm writing a formal legal memo and could not find any explicit form of writing a plural letter grade (as in the example below).

Timmy made one C. His other grades were all As and Bs. (A's and B's?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a somewhat reliable article (on grammarglitchcentral.com), which talks about *The Chicago Manual of Style*.

As per [the article](http://www.grammarglitchcentral.com/tag/the-chicago-manual-of-style/):

> In paragraph 7.60 on page 367, the Manual states that academic grade
>   letters are usually capitalized and not italicized.  This paragraph
>   also says, "No apostrophe is required in the plural."  Here are some
>   good examples:
>
> - My daughter had all As on her last report card.
> - There are only two Cs on Paul's entire high school transcript.
> - If I have one B and four As for this term, what is my grade point average?
>
> PLEASE NOTE: According to the Manual (paragraph 7.14 on page 353),
>   this rule does NOT apply to lower case letters used like words in
>   text.  An apostrophe is used to form the plural of these so references
>   like a's will not be confused with the word as or i's with the word
>   is.  Here are some examples:
>
> - Writers should mind their grammar p's and q's.
> - Algebra is full of x's and y's.

Comment: So, if you ever write for Chicago University Press, that's what you should do. Everybody else does whatever they like. Apostrophe's are silent, after all.